# How to add AD Security group to SharePoint Line Item Permission?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, jsom, active-directory, microsoft-flow

I have a few AD Security Groups (containing about 250 - 300 people in each group).
**I am looking for a solution to add and remove the AD Security Group to/from the SharePoint's "Line Item" permissions.**

I have checked a few solutions that add a person/persons to SharePoint's "Line Item" permissions. (But this alone doesn't help)

Is there any possible solution to achieve this? Either by JSOM/ SharePoint Designer Workflow/ MS Flow?

Kindly Help! Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to add/remove AD group to/from list item automatically?

You can use a SharePoint 2010 platform workflow to achieve it. In your workflow, you can use **Impersonation Step** and use "**Remove List Item permissions**" or "**Replace List Item Permissions**" action to remove or replace AD groups' permission.

A blog for your reference:
[How to give item level permission through SharePoint workflow?](http://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/how-to-give-item-level-permission-through-sharepoint-workflow/)